# Remove conditions in DataTables SearchBuilder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, datatable, datatables

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    searchBuilder: {
       depthLimit: 1,
        conditions: {
             string: {
                '=': null
                     }
                 }
             },
         dom: 'Qfrtip'
   });
```

In this scenario , `'=' equals` condition was removed for the `string` type data.
But when using popup **[SearchBuilder](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchbuilder/customConditions)** it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do this. [SearchBuilder](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchbuilder/examples/customisation/buttonOptions.html)

Here is the `code`

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    language: {
                        searchBuilder: {
                            button: {
                                0: 'Filter',
                                1: 'Filter (one applied)',
                                _: 'Filter (%d)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'searchBuilder',
                            config: {
                                depthLimit: 1,
                                conditions: {
                                    string: {
                                        '=': null,
                                        '!=': null
                                    },
                                    num: {
                                        '=': null,
                                        '!=': null
                                    },
                                },

                            }
                        }
                    ],
                   dom: 'Bfrtip'
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Here the [language](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.searchBuilder.button) option was used to change the name of the `button`. and other customizations are inside the `buttons` braces. Replace the `dom` attributes like below to [align](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) the table properly.

```
 dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
```